# Wordpress do_shortcode with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Here is the code

`jQuery('#home_page_banner').html('<?php echo do_shortcode("[banner id="6135"]"); ?>');`

result:

[image: enter image description]

Comment: What does you short code <?php echo do_shortcode("[banner id="6135"]"); ?> do? What HTML does it generate?

Comment: issue with the code [banner id="6135"] , I think you need to replace that double quote with single quote

Comment: <?php echo do_shortcode("[banner id='6135']"); ?>  try this

Comment: Please try this. It might helps you.

jQuery('#home_page_banner').html('<?php echo do_shortcode("[banner id=' + 6135 + ']"); ?>');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this below code for shortcode

```
$('#home_page_banner').html(<?php echo do_shortcode('[banner id="6135"]'); ?>);
```

OR

```
jQuery('#home_page_banner').html(<?php echo do_shortcode('[banner id="6135"]'); ?>);
```

Comment: this work for inline js. but not work for external js. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: copy your js function and add in footer.php before body tag. because php code dose not support in .js file

Comment: For me it worked after adding `json_encode`: `jQuery('#home_page_banner').html(<?php echo json_encode(do_shortcode('[banner id="6135"]')); ?>);`

Answer (score 0):

No really sure why you would want to do this as it is quite bad practice to use other code to create other code. You could include the shortcode directly to the page template and then just use conditional tags, if you don't want it to be shown on all pages.

Based on the div id you have, is_front_page() would do the trick for you. If for some reason you want to create with jQuery, you could checkout the WP Rest API.

[WP Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: Because i check screen resolution with js. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

This full code.
`function jsUpdateSize(){ 
    var width = window.innerWidth ||document.documentElement.clientWidth ||document.body.clientWidth; 
    if(width <= 450){
        jQuery('#home_page_banner').html('');
        jQuery('#banner_a1').html('');
    }else if(width <= 850){
        jQuery('#home_page_banner').html('');
        jQuery('#banner_a1').html('');
    }else{
        jQuery('#home_page_banner').html('');
        jQuery('#banner_a1').html('');
    }
}

window.onload = jsUpdateSize;
window.onresize = jsUpdateSize;`